# How do I convert an NSString value to NSMutableData? currency character

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsdata

How do I convert an NSString currency character value to NSMutableData?

```
NSString* str = @"€120";
[mutableData appendData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];
```

Print mutableData and out  **?120**  change the character
 **€** for the character
 **?**

How can I add this character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `€` is not an ASCII character, as it did not exist at the time the ASCII charset was defined, so you can't use `NSASCIIStringEncoding` to encode it. If you use a more modern string encoding that supports the `€` character, it will work. `NSUTF8StringEncoding` is generally a good choice.

Comment: I tried with NSUTF8StringEncoding and out   " ,Ç120 "

Comment: @JoseLuisTovarJimenez In what encoding? Make sure that the encoding you use to read the `NSMutableData` later on is the same encoding as you used to encode it in the first place (in this case, you should ensure that it's UTF-8)

Comment: @JoseLuisTovarJimenez I did a test, re-encoding the data as a `NSString` with all the various encodings to find out which one would return ",Ç120". Turns out it's `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` that does that. So either change whatever's reading your data to read it as UTF-8 instead of Mac OS Roman (which I'd recommend, as Mac OS Roman is an obsolete string encoding), or encode the string as `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`. You have to make sure your readers and writers are always using the same encoding.